# SSL: Do I need to secure every endpoint

Tags: api, security, ssl, oauth-2.0

I'm currently building several web apps (built as SPA using Angular) connected to an API. These apps and the API are all using SSL.

Recently, some of our client needed to connect to our API for authentication purpose (using the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant from OAuth2) but his website **is not** using SSL.

So my question is related to security. If the API is using SSL but the request origin (my client's website) is not, are the data send to the API secure?

Using the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant from OAuth2, user credentials are actually send as POST toward the API. Those **MUST** be encrypted (man-in-the-middle attack).

From what I understood, it is still secure as the client need to handshake the server using it's cipher. But I would like to be sure so, explanation are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your API is only accessible via SSL and if the client is properly(!!) checking your certificate to prevent man in the middle attacks then the data sent between the client (i.e. your clients server) and your API are secured but only for this connection. This protection does not extend to data sent to the web site itself in plain text, i.e. login by the user:

```
 user(browser)  <-- http --> website of client <-- https --> API
                   ^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^^
                  INSECURE                         SECURE
```

This means a password sent by the user to the clients website and then forwarded to your API is protected in the second step only but not in the first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the actual behavior is that on the client's website, there will be a login form. On submit, the data will be sent asynchronously (Ajax) to the API. Are the data secure in that case?

Comment: @lkartono: again, the data transport is secured from the website to your API only, not between browser and web site. Which means they are obviously not secure since they can be intercepted by an attacker between browser and website.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here at involved two different circumstances as below.

1)  User exchanges the information with your client websites. **(non-secure channel)**

As you say the client website hasn’t use SSL, it means all personal information of the end-users will be transmitted in to plain text and cyber criminals can easily gain access of the data by acting man-in-the-middle, eavesdropping and other cyber attacks.

2)  Client website data communicate with API. **(secure channel)**

In this case, your client website is non-secure but your API is secure using HTTPS protocol as a result all communication between the client website and API will transit into encryption manner, so no one can interrupt the data during transmission.